# Caliburn Micro actions

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am confused with one thing. When I remove parameter `(string firstName)` from the methods (or from one of them) called `ClearText` and `CanClearText`, the button doesn't become disabled when the data is cleared.

Can you explain what Happens?

this is property;

```
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return _firstName;
    }
    set
    {
        _firstName = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
    }
}
```

these are the methods:

```
public bool CanClearText(string firstName)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName);
}

public void ClearText(string firstName)
{
    FirstName = "";
}
```

this is the corresponding textbox and button

```
<TextBox x:Name ="FirstName" MinWidth="100" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
<Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ClearText"> Clear Names </Button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be, I use Caliburn.Micro and use `CanXXX` with no parameters without any issues. It seems though you would want in your `CanClearText` the code: `return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName);`, since you would want to be able to clear spaces/whitespace.

Comment: I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k (time: 1:05:57 )on youtube and the author also used parameters in these methods.. it is interesing why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you are not using the parameters passed to the action and guard so there is really no need for it.

You can also use properties as action guards as well

```
public string FirstName {
    get {
        return _firstName;
    }
    set {
        _firstName = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanClearText);
    }
}

public bool CanClearText {
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName);
    }
}

public void ClearText() {
    FirstName = "";
}
```

What was happening before was that the UI was unaware of any changes to regarding the action's guard. Using the property approach and notifying the UI that it should recheck the guard will update the button's availability.

Any by using the property approach you can also take advantage of binding to the action guard. Like for example

if there is no reason to clear the text as it is empty then you can also hide the button.

```xml
<TextBox x:Name ="FirstName" MinWidth="100" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
<Border x:Name="CanClearText" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
    <Button x:Name="ClearText" Content="Clear Names" />
</Border>
```

Through Caliburn.Micro automatically binding the `CanClearText` border's visibility to the property it will hide whenever the `CanClearText` property is *false*.